# How to restore KerasClassfier?

Tags: keras, python-3.6

After saved weights and json configuration of a KerasClassifier model https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py I need to restore it and verify results.
But if I restore weight and model then I have a Sequential object, how can I rebuild original KerasClassifier from that??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how can I rebuild original KerasClassifier from that"? How to instantiate `KerasClassifier` with given `Sequential`?

Comment: Hey, can you post some bits of code and be more precise about what you mean with "restore and verify results"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood you correcly, but propose following solution. `KerasClassifier` inherits from `BaseWrapper` which has the following `__init__` signature:

```
def __init__(self, build_fn=None, **sk_params):
    self.build_fn = build_fn
    self.sk_params = sk_params
    self.check_params(sk_params)
```

okay, what's the build_fn and sk_params?

> The `build_fn` should construct, compile and return a Keras model, which
>       will then be used to fit/predict. One of the following
>       three values could be passed to `build_fn`:
>       1. A function
>       2. An instance of a class that implements the `__call__` method
>       3. None. This means you implement a class that inherits from either
>       `KerasClassifier` or `KerasRegressor`. The `__call__` method of the
>       present class will then be treated as the default `build_fn`.
>       ...
>       `sk_params` takes both model parameters and fitting parameters. Legal model
>       parameters are the arguments of `build_fn`. Note that like all other
>       estimators in scikit-learn, `build_fn` should provide default values for
>       its arguments, so that you could create the estimator without passing any
>       values to `sk_params`.
>       ...
>       some commints are omitted

you can read full comment at [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L28) and [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L37) links.
As the `build_fn` expects the function which returns compiled keras model (no matter what it is - `Sequential` or just `Model`) - you can pass as value function which returns loaded model.

**Edit**  also you should call `fit` with some params to restore model using that approach.

**load model as build_fn**

`fit` method invokes a `build_fn`, hence each time you try to train such classifier you will load and then fit loaded clssifier.
For example:

```
from keras.models import load_model  # or another method - but this one is simpliest
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

def load_model(*args, **kwargs):
    """probably this function expects sk_params, so you can use it in theory"""
    path="my_model.hd5"
    model = load_model(path)
    return model

keras_classifier = KerasClassifier(load_model, sk_params)  # use your sk_params
keras_classifier.fit(X_tr, y_tr)  # I use slice (1, input_shape) to train
```

- it will work, as the loaded model almost trained & compiled. But it gives a small shift for your model even if you'll call it with a batch of size 1 and for 1 epoch.

**load via build_fn closure**

Also you can load the model first (if you wish to provide path easily and it's unnacceptable to hardcode path), then return a function which is *"build_fn - acceptable"*:

```
def load_model_return_build_fn(path):
    model = load_model(path)
    def build_fn(*args, **kwars):
         """probably this function expects sk_params"""
         return model  # defined above
    return build_fn

build_fn = load_model_return_build_fn("model.hd5")

keras_classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn, sk_params)  # use your sk_params
keras_classifier.fit(X_tr, y_tr)  # I use slice (1, input_shape) to train
```

**assign a model to it's attribute**

If you plan just load and use pre-trained model, you can use any to load it, assign to the `model` attribute and *don't* call `fit`.

```
build_fn = load_model_return_build_fn("model.hd5")
# or the function which realy builds and fits a model
keras_classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn, sk_params)  # use your sk_params
keras_classifier.model = model  # assign model here, don't call fit
```

- that case you set model explicitly to it's attribute. Note that build_fn should be a coorrect one build_fn - otherwise it doesn't  pass the `self.check_params(sk_params)` test.

**Inherit from KerasClassifier (not so easy as I've thought)**
After all, the best solution I know is inherit from `KerasClassifier` and add a `load` and/or `from_file` method.

```
class KerasClassifierLoadable(KerasClassifier):
    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, path, *args, **kwargs):
        keras_classifier = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        keras_classifier.model = load_model(path)
        outp_shape = keras_classifier.model.layers[-1].output_shape[-1]
        if outp_shape > 1:
            keras_classifier.classes_ = np.arange(outp_shape, dtype='int32')
        else:
            raise ValueError("Inconsistent output shape: outp_shape={}".format(outp_shape))
        keras_classifier.n_classes_ = len(keras_classifier.classes_)
        return keras_classifier

    def load(self, path):
        self.model = load_model(path)
        outp_shape = keras_classifier.model.layers[-1].output_shape[-1]
        if outp_shape > 1:
            keras_classifier.classes_ = np.arange(outp_shape, dtype='int32')
        else:
            raise ValueError("Inconsistent output shape: outp_shape={}".format(outp_shape))
        self.n_classes_ = len(self.classes_)
```

here we shoul set self.classes_ to the correct class labels - but I use just an integer values from `range(0, n_classes).

Usage (the `build_fn` can be any appropiate `build_fn`):

```
keras_classifier = KerasClassifierLoadable.from_file("model.hd5", build_fn=build_fn)

keras_classifier = KerasClassifierLoadable(build_fn=build_fn)
keras_classifier.load("model.hd5")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two files model.json and weights.h5, then you can easily load the model and use it as you want.

```
from keras.models import model_from_json

json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")

# evaluate loaded model on test data
loaded_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
score = loaded_model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (loaded_model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
```

Comment: I've allready use your code but I need to rebuild the original KerasClassifier because it will output directly class prediction and not probabilities. I wonder if there is a simply way to rebuild the original Keras Classifier from the Sequential stored model